# Get MS Office ApplicationID programmatically

Tags: c#, c++, vba, ms-office, office-automation

My Microsoft Office 2013 installation has an ApplicationId value that I need to get programmatically 
(it is `0ff1ce15-a989-479d-af46-f275c6370663`. For MS Office 2010 installation it is `59a52881-a989-479d-af46-f275c6370663`)
So eventually I have 2 questions:

1. Are these values identical for same MS office versions on different PCs?
2. How to programmatically get these values for 2007-2016 in C++? (through Automation, or some other way).

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

was looking for another answer so thought I would reply, yes they are the same on different machines though each office version will have it's own unique ID as you know.

I was using c# and used a WMI query to look for the details in the class SoftwareLicensingProduct though it is also found in OfficeSoftwareProtectionProduct below is my query

```
"SELECT ID, ApplicationId, PartialProductKey, Name, ProductKeyID FROM SoftwareLicensingProduct  WHERE ApplicationId = '" + sApplicationId+"' AND PartialProductKey <> NULL"
```

I have code that runs before that identifies the version of office on the workstation and the result of that query will set the relevant ApplicationID

```
            if (sVersion == "2013")
        {
             sApplicationId = "Office 15 Application ID";

        }
        else if (sVersion == "2016")
        {
             sApplicationId = "Office 16 Application ID";
        }
```

To get the version of Office that is on the box you could either parse the registry or not sure if you can do this in c++ I launched Word hidden and retrieved the application version then used a Case statement

```
            switch (appVersion.Version.ToString())
        {
            case "15.0":
                sVersion = "2013";
                break;
            case "16.0":
                sVersion = "2016";
                break;
            case "14.0":
                sVersion = "2010";
                break;
            default:
                sVersion = "No Version detected!";
                break;
        }
```

I know I could probably  automate this further and pull out the ApplicationID from the WMI query but not got round to that yet.

Not sure if this helps?

Barry